# Using "dplyr" to calculate specific ratio for for each row of dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I know that the topic doesn't describe what I want to do, but belive it's hard to explain in just one senetece.
I have a data frame in the form shown below:

```
       ID V_tour
     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1206818      0
 2 1238530      0
 3 1238530      0
 4 1241498      0
 5 1228139      1
 6 1228139      1
 7 1334957      0
 8 1328103      1
 9 1206818      1
10 1334957      0
11 1239023      0
12 1241498      0
13 1152361      1
```

What I want to do is that for each **specific ID** (these IDs may be repeated more than 1 time), I want to calculate the ratio of the number of times we have 1 in column "v_tour" to the total number of rows for **other IDs**. To elaborate more, let's choose ID, 1206818. For this ID, I have to look at other IDs and find the ratio of the number of times that number 1 repeated to the total number. For ID 1206818, 4/11 because for other IDs number 1 has been repeated 4 times in v_tour column and the total number of other rows are 11, so the ratio is 4/11. Please note that since ID 1206818 repeated two times, for each time we have to show 4/11 in front of that ID
So the expected result would be:

```
       ID V_tour    ratio
     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1206818      0     4/11
 2 1238530      0     5/11
 3 1238530      0     5/11
 4 1241498      0     5/11
 5 1228139      1     3/11
 6 1228139      1     3/11
 7 1334957      0     5/11
 8 1328103      1     4/12
 9 1206818      1     4/11
10 1334957      0     5/11
11 1239023      0     5/12
12 1241498      0     5/11
13 1152361      1     4/12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can count total number of 1's in the data and subtract it with number of 1's for that `ID`, divide this number by (total number of rows - number of rows in the group).

```
library(dplyr)

total_one <- sum(df$V_tour)
n <- nrow(df)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(formula = paste(total_one - sum(V_tour), n-n(), sep = '/'),
         ratio = (total_one - sum(V_tour))/(n-n())) 

#        ID V_tour formula ratio
#     <int>  <int> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 1206818      0 4/11    0.364
# 2 1238530      0 5/11    0.455
# 3 1238530      0 5/11    0.455
# 4 1241498      0 5/11    0.455
# 5 1228139      1 3/11    0.273
# 6 1228139      1 3/11    0.273
# 7 1334957      0 5/11    0.455
# 8 1328103      1 4/12    0.333
# 9 1206818      1 4/11    0.364
#10 1334957      0 5/11    0.455
#11 1239023      0 5/12    0.417
#12 1241498      0 5/11    0.455
#13 1152361      1 4/12    0.333
```

Added an additional `formula` column to explain how `ratio` is calculated, you can remove that column.